# Cast string to first element of a new list in function call

Tags: python, string, list, casting

I'm looking for the Python way to take a string and pass it to a function as a list, like so:

```
word = 'abc'
result = crazyfunction(cast(word,[]))
```

so that `crazyfunction` will receive a list like this:

```
word[0] = 'abc'
```

instead of a string.

The goal is to cast in the function parameter, instead of having to do an assignment before each call.

Comment: Just jumping into Python, so please cut slack on what may be a really newbie question.  I did spend some time trying to Google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, it looks like it would be as simple as building a list. Just call the function like this: `crazyfunction(['abc'])`

EDIT: Just tested it in the console:

```
>>> def printfirst(lst):
...     print lst[0]
...
>>> printfirst('hello')
h
>>> printfirst(['hello'])
hello
```

Comment: when I actually get there, I have a variable (though in one place I have a string literal which that will work great for).

Comment: So, instead of building a list with a literal, do it with your variable instead, like x would be built as `[x]`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it was that easy.

Comment: @Lance This basically will happen automatically if you do `def printfirst(*lst)`, in that the first item of the `lst` tuple will be `'hello'`. You'll just have a tuple instead of a list.